# AngularJS ng-cloak: empty page is displaying in IE9 when browser cache is cleared

Tags: angularjs

I just encountered a weird issue on angular's ng-cloak. When I cleared my IE9 browser's cache and close and open my browser again, when i accessed the page, it display empty page :( but when i tried to refresh the page it the page is now displaying.

Comment: Check your console for any errors.

Comment: I already checked my console but unfortunately I did not found any errors. I debugging this errors for more than a day. :(

Comment: Are you using console.log() anywhere in your script code??